# Align text vertically in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

How can I vertically & horizontally align a text in the main content of a jQuery webpage?
I want to align "REZA SAN STUDIOS" to be in the middle of the page with vertical align middle as well.

I've tried to use position: absolute and relative and align them to left, top 50% but different mobile browser will not display them in the middle. Some more towards the left and some more to the right.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!-- MAINPAGE -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d">
  <div data-role="header" id="headerpageone">
    <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline"><h1>☰</h1></a>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" id="contentone">
    <h1>REZA SAN STUDIOS</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" id="footerpageone" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#intro" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" data-transition="slideup" ><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family:'CoreHumanistSans';
  font-weight:500;
  letter-spacing:0.05em;
  font-size:14px;   
}
#headerpageone {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;
}
#contentone {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#footerpageone {
    text-align:center;
}
.copy {
  padding-top:20px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LRyz8/

Comment: Have you thought about setting the width to 100% and then the child element to margin: 0 auto ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#contentone
{
    position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     height: 50%;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LRyz8/2/

Comment: Hey it works! I think I missed the width and padding part. There must be some default padding, margin in the jquery mobile css. Thanks so much Kapil!

Answer (score 1):

Use;

```
<div style="display:table-cell; text-align : center; vertical-align:middle"> ..... </div>
```

Check out at @

```
http://jsfiddle.net/FFG8y/
```